# How pass parameter object in scala function?

Tags: javascript, function, scala

With javaScript I can do something like this:

```
var parameters = {}
for (object in objects) {
    if (someCondition(object)) {
        parameters.[object.getName()] = object.getValue();
    }
}
myFunction(parameters)
```

The idea is to collect *parameters* and pass them as object (!) not as array to the function. How do something similar with scala?

Comment: parameters.[object.getName()] is wrong... no need to use dot after parameters

Answer (score 1):

This is what `Map`s are used for. In JavaScript, we use objects interchangeably for "records" and "dictionaries". In Scala, and most statically typed languages, we use `Map`s instead for the dictionary use case. One advantage of `Map`s compared to JS dictionaries is that the keys can be of a type different than `String`.

So I would translate your example as the following, with `ObjClass` being the class of your `object`s:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val parameters = mutable.Map.empty[String, ObjClass]
for (obj <- objects) {
  parameters(obj.name) = obj.value
}
myFunction(parameters)
```

Note that the above is very imperative, and can be rewritten in a more functional style like this:

```
val parameters = (
  for (obj <- objects)
    yield obj.name -> obj.value
).toMap
```

Comment: The goal is to call myFunction with 1 or 2 or more parameters, not pass Map or tuple object to it. `val parameters = (for (obj <- objects) yield obj.name -> obj.value).toMap` returns a `Map` not parameters object.

Comment: @Cherry your `parameters` object acts essentially in the same way as an associative array, which is implemented as `Map` in Scala. You get the same behaviour but what you lose is static type inference and verification that is one of the major benefits of a statically typed language.

Comment: @Cherry I don't get it, then. What is the definition of `myFunction`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with case classes. Define default values as default parameters.

```
case class Parameters(
  param1:String = "a"
  param2:Int = 1
)

val params = Parameters("b", 2)
myFunction(params)

val paramsWithDefault = Parameters()
myFunction(paramsWithDefault)
```

You can get something like jquery `$.extend` behavior with inbuilt features (case classes and default values) of scala. But actually javascript is a dynamic language where you can merge objects, where as scala is static. You define your object in compile time. So what we are doing here is not exactly merging objects.

Furthermore, using `parameter objects` is not common in scala for clarity of the code.

Comment: Not in parameters case class I guess. It really doesn't matter where the `myFunction` is.